# Listpicker goes blank after setting setting selected index

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit

I have listpicker control in my wp7 app. And I want To Set Selected Index as per my needs. Lets Suppose I Have 100 items in my listpicker If I Set The selected index below 40 it goes well. But When I set Selected index above 50 it goes blank and UI not refreshed but on backend it shows correct item.

Sample Project : http://yaariyan.net/Test_Project.rar

In this project you can get

1. All Source
2. XAP file to test as well
3. Steps To Reproduce
4. Snapshot of Error

Just Play with my last two button you can easily reproduce issue.

I am using windows phone 7.1.1 SDK And Silverlight Took Kit November 2011 Version.

DLL is also in my folder That I am referring in my project

Comment: Please reduce your problem to the smallest possible size which still contains the issue. No, I do not know the size of your source but linking to it leads me to believe it wouldn't fit nicely here - a good sign it's not a reduced problem. Also, no offense, but I'm not very inclined to click a random link in this day and age...

Comment: @lc. Its just one page and its not more than 1.5 MB as it conatins the silverlight toolkit dll that i am using for better rectification of problem. And I just uploaded the sample code as there are many versions and change set of silverlight tookkit. I am using november verion official one

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. I'm afraid I can't come up with a solution yet, but I have narrowed down the problem a bit. I can verify that the problem seems to occur somewhere between `SelectedIndex` 40 and 50 (48 in my case).

What I did to narrow it down was to simply create a new WP solution, add two `ListPicker` controls to the `MainPage.xaml` view, plus a button. I add 50 strings to both lists through code and set the `SelectedIndex` to 0 on the first list and 50 on the second one.

The button does a simple switch of the SelectedIndex properties like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int tempindex = listPicker1.SelectedIndex;
        listPicker1.SelectedIndex = listPicker2.SelectedIndex;
        listPicker2.SelectedIndex = tempindex;
    }
```

I ran the project and ended up with this (the movie says it all, I think):

http://screencast.com/t/T6mZ7FEdUF

Comment: I sorted out this thing. Its a bug in listpicker control of silverlight toolkit. I changeed in source of toolkit and fixed that. Will share it soom as i am on mobile right now :)

Comment: I would love if you could share the source!

Comment: I have set the itemSource binding on the xaml and not on the xaml.cs, it worked, check the other answer. I hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem. What I did was, I binded the ListPicker Itemsource on the .xaml and not on the code behind and it worked perfectly.

this is the .xaml code edited in the file provided by you:

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding LstCountry}" SelectedIndex="55" x:Name="listPickerCountrySignup" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" FullModeHeader="Select Country" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" CacheMode="BitmapCache" >
```

.xaml.cs code

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindList();
            this.DataContext= this;
        }

```
    public class country 
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    List<country> _lstCountry;
    public List<country> LstCountry
    {
        get{return _lstCountry;}
        set{
            if(_lstCountry!=value)
            {
                _lstCountry = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LstCountry");
            }
        }
    }
    void BindList()
    {
        LstCountry = new List<country>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            LstCountry.Add(new country { CountryID = i });
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listPickerCountrySignup.SelectedIndex = 15;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listPickerCountrySignup.SelectedIndex = 25;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listPickerCountrySignup.SelectedIndex = 39;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listPickerCountrySignup.SelectedIndex = 55;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listPickerCountrySignup.SelectedIndex = 75;
    }
}
```